# Dart/Flutter get first DateTime of this week

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart

Using flutter on android I am trying to get the first date of current week. For example today is 13/7/2020, assuming week starts from Saturday the first date of current week will be 11/7/2020.

This for example to get first date of month

```
DateTime firstDay = new DateTime(
  DateTime.now().year,
  DateTime.now().month,
  1,
); //get first date this month
```

The end goal is to get timestamp of that date and fetch entries from sqflite database that is higher than that.

Comment: Check out https://pub.dev/packages/isoweek

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If Sunday is your first day of week.

```
var d = DateTime.now();
var weekDay = d.weekday;
var firstDayOfWeek = d.subtract(Duration(days: weekDay));
```

According to Flutter docs `weekDay` returns

> The day of the week [monday]..[sunday].
>
> - In accordance with ISO 8601
> - a week starts with Monday, which has the value 1.

if Monday is first day of week then

```
var firstDayOfWeek = d.subtract(Duration(days: weekDay - 1));
```

Comment: If Sunday is the first day of the week and if the current day is already Sunday, this answer will return the previous Sunday.

Answer (score 2):

**For Sunday:**

```
DateTime today = DateTime.now();
DateTime _firstDayOfTheweek =
        today.subtract(new Duration(days: today.weekday));
print(_firstDayOfTheweek.day);
```

**For Monday:**

```
DateTime _firstDayOfTheweek =
        today.subtract(new Duration(days: today.weekday - 1));
print(_firstDayOfTheweek.day);
```

**For Saturday:**

```
DateTime _firstDayOfTheweek =
        today.subtract(new Duration(days: today.weekday + 1));
print(_firstDayOfTheweek.day);
```

Comment: This isn't quite correct for Sunday or Saturday.  If the current day is the start of the week, this answer will return the start date of the *previous* week for those cases.

Answer (score 1):

The DateTime class stores int constants for the day of the week which you could use to calculate the start date you need. Something like this should work:

```
void main() {
  var startOfWeek = DateTime.saturday;
  var currentDate = DateTime.now();
  var daysSince = currentDate.weekday + (DateTime.sunday - startOfWeek);

  var result = currentDate.subtract(Duration(days: daysSince));

  print('Date at start of week is $result');
}
```

Comment: If the current day happens to be the start of a new week, the above code can return the start of the previous week.

Answer (score 0):

To get different dates of different days in a week.  We can use this **[isoweek](https://pub.dev/packages/isoweek#isoweek)** package for this. We can use like this :-

```
                        Week currentWeek = Week.current(); 
                        Week weekFromIso = Week.fromISOString(currentWeek.toString());
                        print('Week from ISO string: $weekFromIso');


                        DateTime firstDay= weekFromIso.day(0);
                        String formattedDateFirst = DateFormat('EEE, d MMM').format(firstDay);

                        DateTime secondDay= weekFromIso.day(1);
                        String formattedDateSecond = DateFormat('EEE, d MMM').format(secondDay);
```